# Pygame - Scale_to_length not working 100% of times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have made a pygame game where 2 cars race around a football pitch and try to score a goal. I have added a boost function where a countdown timer starts as long as the up button is being pressed and is stopped when the key is no longer being pressed. When the timer = 0,the boosting feature stops. This works 70-80% of the time, but with strange glitches.

(Glitch 1)Sometimes, even after the up arrow has been let go, the boosted speed stays the same, and the timer does not turn on.

(Glitch 2)Another strange glitch is when the boosttimer has gone to 0, and the user hold down both up and a sideways arrow, then let go of the sidewards arrow(left or right), the boosted speed still says.

I've got my code for the boost below, hope someone can help.

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2
import time

pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()


WIDTH = 1150
HEIGHT = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rocket League")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
start_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
REDGOAL = pygame.Surface((50, 150), pygame.SRCALPHA)
REDGOAL.fill((255, 0, 0))
redgoal_rect = REDGOAL.get_rect(topleft=(0, 340))
redgoal_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(REDGOAL)


REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    REDCAR_ORIGINAL, (255, 0, 0), [(0, 30), (50, 20), (50, 10), (0, 0)])
redangle = 180
redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)

redspeed = 5
dx = 0
dy = 0
x = 800
y = 500
pos_red = Vector2(x,y)
vel_red = Vector2(-redspeed,0)
redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
redangle = 180
redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
def starttimer():
    global timer
    timer -= dt

def starttimer1():
    global timer1
    timer1 -= dt





def redboost():
    font4 = pygame.font.Font(None, 72)
    timer10 = int(timer)
    timer11 = round(timer10, 1)
    timer12 = str(timer11)
    global timer13
    timer13 = font4.render(timer12, False, (255,0,0))


timer = 3
dt = 1

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    redboost()
    print(timer)



    if redrect.top < 0 and vel_red.y < 0:
        redrect.top = 0
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    elif redrect.bottom > screen.get_height() and vel_red.y > 0:
        redrect.bottom = screen.get_height()
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    if redrect.left < 0 and vel_red.x < 0:
        redrect.left = 0
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    elif redrect.right > screen.get_width() and vel_red.x > 0:
        redrect.right = screen.get_width()
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        redangle += 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(-5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        redangle -= 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        vel_red.scale_to_length(10)
        starttimer()


    if  keys[pygame.K_UP] and keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        starttimer()

    elif  keys[pygame.K_UP] and keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        starttimer()

    elif  keys[pygame.K_UP] and keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and keys [pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        starttimer()






    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            vel_red.scale_to_length(5)

    elif timer <= 0:
        vel_red.scale_to_length(5)



    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        vel_red.scale_to_length(2)

    pos_red += vel_red
    redrect.center = pos_red

    if timer <= 0:
        timer = 0
        vel_red.scale_to_length(5)
    elif timer == 0:
        timer = 0
        vel_red.scake_to_length(5)


    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and timer == 0:
        vel_red.scale_to_length(5)


    screen.fill((50,200,50))
    screen.blit(redcar, redrect)
    screen.blit(timer13, (950,750))


    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    dt = clock.tick(30)/1000
```

Comment: why is there an elif with no if before?

Comment: Sorry, it is part of some other code that isn't mentioned in this question.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, but the code snippet provided does not work. It throughs an error about the `elif` that is in the code and not accompanied by an `if`. Also, this code does not seem to have any output mechanism; either printing the glitching speed or showing the graphic. It doesn't seem possible to answer your question without these fixes.

Comment: Sorry, was away for all of yesterday, but edited my code to as minimalistic as I can

Comment: One problem that I can see immediately is `if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:` in the while loop. That clause should be in the event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rearrange the event handling code and scale the velocity vector in the event loop instead of the main loop to start boosting. So when ↑ gets pressed, scale the vector once and reset it when the key gets released. In the while loop you can still check `if keys[pygame.K_UP]:` to reduce the timer, and `if timer <= 0:` scale the vector to 5 again.

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2


pygame.init()

WIDTH = 1150
HEIGHT = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rocket League")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    REDCAR_ORIGINAL, (255, 0, 0), [(0, 30), (50, 20), (50, 10), (0, 0)])
redangle = 180
redspeed = 5
x = 800
y = 500
pos_red = Vector2(x,y)
vel_red = Vector2(-redspeed,0)
redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
redangle = 180
redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)

timer = 3
dt = 1

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Start boosting.
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                vel_red.scale_to_length(10)
            # Slow down.
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                vel_red.scale_to_length(2)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            # Stop boosting. Reset the velocity.
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                vel_red.scale_to_length(5)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                vel_red.scale_to_length(5)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        redangle += 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(-5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        redangle -= 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:  # If boosting.
        timer -= dt

    if timer <= 0:  # Reset the velocity.
        timer = 0
        vel_red.scale_to_length(5)

    # Movement.
    pos_red += vel_red
    redrect.center = pos_red

    # Bounds checking.
    if redrect.top < 0 and vel_red.y < 0:
        redrect.top = 0
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    elif redrect.bottom > screen.get_height() and vel_red.y > 0:
        redrect.bottom = screen.get_height()
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    if redrect.left < 0 and vel_red.x < 0:
        redrect.left = 0
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)
    elif redrect.right > screen.get_width() and vel_red.x > 0:
        redrect.right = screen.get_width()
        pos_red = Vector2(redrect.center)

    screen.fill((50,200,50))
    screen.blit(redcar, redrect)
    pygame.display.set_caption('{:.2f}'.format(timer))
    # Call either display.flip or display.update but not both.
    pygame.display.flip()
    dt = clock.tick(30)/1000

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Ok thanks very much about that, works very well, I've never thought of putting Keydown in the event loop, very helpful